# Issue with downloading PDF from S3 on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, amazon-s3, content-type

I'm facing an issue on downloading PDF files from Amazon S3 using Chrome.

When I click a link, my controller redirect the request to the file's URL on S3.

It works perfectly with Firefox, but nothing happens with Chrome.

Yet, if I perform a right click -> *Save location as* will download the file ...

And even a copy-paste of the S3 URL into Chrome will lead to a blank screen ...

Here is some information returned by curl:

```
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2012 15:34:09 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Feb 2012 04:45:24 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/x-pdf
Content-Length: 50024
Server: AmazonS3
```

My guesses are related to an issue with the content type ... but all I tried didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical [Internet media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) for a PDF document is actually `application/pdf` as defined in [The application/pdf Media Type (RFC 3778)](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778.txt) - please note that `application/x-pdf`, while commonly encountered and listed as a media type in [Portable Document Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) as well, is notably absent from the official [Application Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html) listed by the [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](http://www.iana.org/).

I'm not aware of why and when `application/x-pdf` came to life, but apparently the [Chrome PDF Plugin does not open application/x-pdf documents](http://code.google.com/p/firefox-mac-pdf/issues/detail?id=176) as of today.

Consequently you should be able to trigger a different behavior in Chrome by changing the media type of the stored objects accordingly.

#### Alternative (for authenticated requests)

Another approach would be to [Force a PDF to download](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/comment/7045) instead of letting Chrome attempt to open it, which can be done by means of triggering the `Content-Diposition: attachment` header with your `GET` request - please see the S3 documentation for [GET Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) on how to achieve this via the `response-content-disposition` request parameter, specifically `response-content-disposition=attachment` as demonstrated there in section *Sample Request with Parameters Altering Response Header Values*.

This is only available for authenticated requests though, see section *Request Parameters*:

> **Note**
>
> You must sign the request, either using an Authorization header
> or a Pre-signed URL, when using these parameters. They can not be used
> with an unsigned (anonymous) request.

Comment: When I did that I got "Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET requests." -- how do I make authenticated requests?

Comment: @Kerry: You probably mean the alternative approach, right? Unfortunately this is indeed only available for authenticated requests; I've updated my answer with the respective quote from the S3 documentation for [GET Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) now, sorry for being misleading here.

Answer (score 7):

There is an html based solution to this.  Since chrome is up to date with HTML5, we can use the shiny new `download` attribute!

`<a href="http://www.domain.com/painful.pdf">Broken</a>`

`<a href="http://www.domain.com/painful.pdf" download="notsopainful">Works</a>`