# How do you force a file to download from Amazon S3 using the Amazon SDK for PHP?

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have an app that is using the Amazon S3 for storing files.  I ran into a problem where a large PDF was not downloading using chrome.  Smaller PDFs work great, but this larger would not work.  I don't believe it is an issue with the PDF, I suspect that it has to do with the size of the file.

When viewing the file in the browser here is the code I am using:

```
header("Content-type: $filetype");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$filename."\"");
$response = $s3->get_object(AMAZON_BUCKET, $filepath);   
echo $response->body;
```

This works great for smaller files, but today I ran into a problem where this large PDF would not show.  I am thinking the file is too big to be rendered. Therefore I decided to try to force files to be downloaded instead of viewed in the browser if they are too big. So here is the code I am trying to get to work, but I must be doing something wrong because it is not working.

```
    $response = $s3->get_object(AMAZON_BUCKET, $filepath, array(
      'response' => array(
        'content-type' => $filetype,
        'content-disposition' => 'attachment'
       )
    ));
```

How do I use the Amazon SDK for PHP to force a **large** file to download?

Comment: It might be that your PHP script is running out of memory if the file is too large. Have you checked the error log (or enabled display errors? Do you get a "response" at all? More clues as to where it breaks might help.

Comment: I am increasing the memory to 82M.  The file I am having trouble with is 43 mb.

Comment: And the other part of the question: can you desciibe more the symptoms of it not working? Do you get any resposne from the server - a 500 error, a "warning" or "notice". Anything in the logs?

Comment: It hangs for a while, and then gives me a This webpage is not found. but is really is there.... not sure why that error happens.  The other thing I tried was to get the URL for the object and then go directly to it, but all I get is a blank page.  Interesting though if I use that same URL in safari, it works, just not chrome.

Comment: If I disable chrome from viewing PDFs in the browser "about:plugins" then have it go to the URL provided by Amazon then it will work in chrome.  Chrome is defaulted to view the PDF in the browser so I can not depend on someone disabling the plugin to download the file.

Comment: In Chrome, go "tools" "Developer Tools", "Network" and then make the request again. tell you the status and response of the call. Double click on the line and it'll tell you more.

Comment: Cool - so the problem is that the PDF inline viewer in Chrome doesn't work? Not really related to PHP or Amazon at all? Perhaps you'll got more luck by retagging/ rewording the question to mention that (and not Amazon/PHP)?

Comment: Given the adjusted question scope my answer to [Issue with downloading PDF from S3 on Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9099933) might be relevant or provide more clues/hints how to approach the problem eventually (depends on your exact use case of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you download the entire file from S3 to your webserver's memory and then send it to the user's browser. If the file is large, this can result in exceeding `memory_limit` or even `max_execution_time`. (Admittedly, I don't know why your case is Chrome-specific..)

A more elegant way would be to redirect the user to download the file directly from S3. You can even [set custom headers](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html?r=8109) to be part of your request, so you can force the download dialog. Use [`get_object_url()`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_url) instead of `get_object()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I think I will rethink the way I am doing this.  The interesting problem though is that when I take the url returned from amazon from the get_object_url and put that url in chrome it is canceled by the browser.  If I do that same thing in safari it will download the file.  Do you have any idea why chrome would not download it and safari would?

Comment: I added the headers and it fixed the problem with chrome.