# Amazon S3 Restrict Access To File By Referer - Chrome Has Issues

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, chromium

This is what my Amazon S3 bucket policy looks like (generated in part, using the [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)):

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1350503700228",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1350503699292",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::files.example.com/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:Referer": [
            "http://example.com/*",
            "http://www.example.com/*"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What the bucket policy is supposed to do is - throw a '403 Forbidden' error if any file in the bucket is accessed directly or from a referrer other than `(www.)example.com`.

It seems to work, except that Chrome seems to have issues with PDF files served in this manner (for instance, images load just fine). So, any PDF from `files.example.com` (with referrer based restrictions) seems to be loading forever in Chrome (latest version, on Ubuntu 12.04). Firefox on the other hand loads the PDF, which is less than 100KB in size, in a snap.

Any idea as to what I am / could be doing wrong?

**PS:** If I right-click and select 'Save As..' Chrome is able to download the file. I don't understand why it's not showing it.

Answer (score 2):

I checked developed tools on Chrome and found that Chrome pdf plugin requests pdf in multiple chunks. First chunk will have correct referer but all consequent chunk will have `https://s3.amazonaws.com/....` instead of `http://mywebsite.com`. Adding `https://s3.amazonaws.com/*` into bucket policy list solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your bucket and double-check the MIME type specified on the file (metadata tab).  It should be `Content-Type: application/pdf`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the response-content-disposition to "attachment" as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9099933/568383